# Batch file replace string in filename of copied files

Tags: batch-file, command

I have about 10 batch files which copy *.txt files from root folder to their subfolders. The code for copying is following:

```
cscript ..\myScripts\CopyFiles.vbs "." "..\myScripts\Copy.cfg" "scripts_A" "((.+\.txt)|(.+\.ps1))"
```

Every single batch file copy *.txt files to folder with the same name (A.bat ->scripts_A, B.bat ->scripts_B). I need to have right filename in each subfolder (in folder scripts_A files need to be operationAfirst.txt, operationAsecond.txt, in folder scripts_B files operationBfirst.txt, operationBsecond.txt). So the result should be following:

```
for folder scripts_A:
operationAfirst.txt
operationAsecond.txt
for folder scripts_B:
operationBfirst.txt
operationBsecond.txt
```

All *.txt files in subfolders are usually clones of *.txt files for folder scripts_A. I just need to update their filename. Is there any posibility how to edit batch file, which can replace "A" string in filename for "B" in batch used for folder scripts_B?

Comment: My head is twirling: I have a batch ... I have about 10 batch files ... showing the arguments of a vbscript. You don't make very clear what you want to achive. Renaming files in folders which are to abstract to see any pattern to know to rename how.

Comment: ok, I will to try explain it better. I've got 10 batch files (A.bat, B.bat, C.bat.....,J.bat). Every single batch file copy *.txt files to folder with the same name (A.bat ->scripts_A, B.bat ->scripts_B). As you can see from script I am using, I copy all *.txt files to subfolders. But I need to have right filename in each subfolder (in folder scripts_A files need to be operationAfirst.txt, operationBsecond.txt, in folder scripts_B files operationBfirst.txt, operationBsecond.txt). I know it's little bit confusing.

Comment: please don't put essential information in comments, but edit your question. Why not have one batch with cmdline arg stating which folder to use? Is the file name operationAfirst.txt to be taken literal or only an abstract?

Comment: I need to have these specific batch files when I copy *.txt file to only one subfolder. It is an abstract.

Comment: I see you have wrongly named files in your folders, but up to now you don't say how they are named. I only **guess** there might be files operationAfirst.txt in folder script_B and shall be renamed operationBfirst.txt?

Comment: Yes, you're right. In folder scripts_B I have files operationAfirst.txt, etc.. And this files need to be renamed to operationBfirst.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repairing the outcome of a poorly designed setup, I'd prefer to give hints how to alter that situation. So against the best of one's knowledge this batch will do the rename:

```
@Echo off
Setlocal
CD /D X:\where\ever\you\start
For %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J) Do For /F "delims=" %%B in (
  'Dir /B %CD%\Script_%%A\operation*.txt    |Findstr /V "operation%%A"'
) Do Call :RenFiles %%A "%%~fB"
Goto :Eof

:RenFiles
Set OldName=%~nx2
Set NewName=operation%1%OldName:~10%
Echo Ren %2 %NewName%
```

Change the path in the cd statement.
The first of the stacked for loops iterates the letters A to J.
The second one executes dir in the folder script_(letter) listing all
files starting with operation and the extension .txt. The findstr 
then removes all correct names for this folder.
The remaining are then arguments to the called subroutine

The subroutine builds the new name from the prefix operation 
followed by the folder letter and the original name from 11th place
(offset 10).

As long as the echo remaines in front of the ren it only shows what it would do.